# Не получается правильно отправить POST запрос

Tags: python, requests

Не получается правильно отправить POST запрос в request.
Data выглядит так[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал использовать headers и отправлять data в таком формате

```
data = {"object" : [{"action" : "getMatchBetInformation",
                   "matchid" : id}]}
site = requests.post('https://www.statarea.com/actions/controller/',data=data)
```

Comment: В приведённом скриншоте отправляется `form data`, а Вы зачем-то хотите отправить `json`.

Comment: я и без headers отправлял,всё равно присылает пустой ответ

Comment: а ошибка от сервера есть какая то?

Comment: нет,статус код  200 присылает

Comment: добавьте в вопрос пример запроса который вы делаете через requests

Comment: а зачем помещать данные в список?